# UK visa 3 months before the travel date

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Does the the UK rule, to apply for a visa up to 3 months before travel, start from the date of the online application or from the date of the appointment?

Comment: @HankyPanky the difference it makes is that in one case it would be possible to submit an online application in March for a trip in July, and in the other case it would not.

Comment: In applying UK Standard visitor visa in the Philippines, there is a date when you can confirm your application online after that you will choose which appointment date you're going to pass all the documents to their partner (VFS). so my question is what date should the 3 months before the arrival in UK is it start from the date when you confirm the application online OR in the date when you submit all the documents to their partner (VFS). Thank you.

Comment: i got the idea of Phoog, but Im very confused which date the 3 months before the arrival starts

Comment: @Mike Add this clarifying information into the question.

Comment: @Mike your question and comment lead me to wonder whether you understand that the application must be *no more than* three months *before* you travel.  So if you apply on May 21st, your trip can be any day between then and August 20th.

Comment: If my arrival date in UK is August 21 so i can apply on May 22 right? im very confused with the date when you confirm your application "online" and the date when you are going to submit "personally" your documents? I really dont know when is the 3 months prior date should start on that 2 questions. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mike That’s correct. It is the online application date that counts.

Answer (score 1):

It starts from the intended date of travel. The UK Gov website gives this example “You can apply from 16 March if you plan to travel on 16 June”. https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa You book the appointment as part of submitting the online application, and you can change your booked appointment anytime up to 3 weeks before your travel date (the latest acceptable date for the appointment is stated in the email confirmation received after completing the online application). For example, for an intended travel date of 7 June, you could complete the online application on 8 March and have your appointment up to 17 May.

Comment: @Mike No, it starts on the day you submit your application online, which can be no more than 3 months before your date of travel. Your appointment date will be anytime after you’ve completed the online application, up to 3 weeks before your intended travel date (the standard processing time is 15 working days, but this is not 100% guaranteed).

Comment: i see so the 3 months prior to arrival date will start on the day when i complete the application form online NOT on the submission date when i go personally to VFS to submit the documents.